# How to create a regex that will match regardless of the sequence of characters?

Tags: php, regex

Say I am requiring a user to input the certain words provided and he/will just input it on a textbox which will be validated **regardless** of order.I have been looking for answers for hours and I'm stuck :/

e.g. the words should be inputted are: foo, bar, green.

and I can still match it even if the order is **bar green foo**  or **green foo bar**

I pretty much know the very basics of regex but I don't know how to match with this type of condition..
Any answers will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This checks if you have exactly these three words in the input and nothing more:

```
/^(?=.*\bbar\b)(?=.*\bgreen\b)(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?:\s*\b\w+\b\s*){3}$/s
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work.. But I have one question in mind. I see that they are somehow made in order of bar - green - foo. But how was this achieved. Recursively?

Comment: @Rei Not recursively. Firstly it checks if there is a word `bar` in the string, then it checks for word `green`, later for word `foo` and finally it checks if there are 3 words in a string.

Comment: @Rei you can reed about lookahead assertions more here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 4):

simple answer: don't use regex.

Just `explode()` the input, and then check manually if the words are ok. A simple way to check if the input is good is this:

```
if(!array_diff(explode(' ', $input), $valid_words)) {
    // input OK
}
```

Comment: I would have to agree with your statement but I will also make use of the hints not just based on my query. It may not be that ideal but it may come in handy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/59c57

```
<?php 
$str = 'foo, bar, green'; 
$array = explode(',', $str); 
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will check if you have those words in your input:

```
(?=^.*?foo.*$)(?=^.*?bar.*$)(?=^.*?green.*$)^.*$
```

But it does not check if it does not have anything else. In general, I agree to others don't use regular expressions for this thing. Split the input and check against your dictionary.