# Regex to match two exact key=value's regardless of the order

Tags: regex

First, I know my question would be possibly duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138159/how-to-create-a-regex-that-will-match-regardless-of-the-sequence-of-characters), but I need solution which must be correct in 100%. And I am not so good in regexes to achieve this :)

I have maaaaaaaaany requests with few params passed like `...&params=key1=value1|key2=value2|...`. There may be few params and I don't know the order. What I need is to catch request that contains exact `key1=myValue1` and `key2=myValue2`, but they can be like:

- `key1=myValue1|key2=myValue2`
- `key2=myValue2|key1=myValue1`
- `key1=myValue1|key3=myValue3|key2=myValue2`

or even more complicated. What is known:

- `params` is only part of the request, so it can be `?something=other&params=key1=value1|key2=value2` or `?params=key1=value1|key2=value2&something=other`
- inside `params` parameter there are not white chars, only pair(s) of `key=value`'s (separated with `|`)

To be clear: I **know** two pairs of key=value so regex is only for matching requests containing those 2 pairs. Requests could be ordered in different way. I don't have access to request itself, I only work on saved data (as string).

Language where regex will be used is PHP. But I don't have access to full code, because we declare regex in web application interface.

I think I need two positive lookaheads, like `(?=[^\s]*(key1=myValue1)[^\s]*){1}(?=[^\s]*(key2=myValue2)[^\s]*){1}` but I can't get it to work and clock is ticking...

Comment: Which language? How exactly are you applying the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two lookaheads:

```
^(?=.*\bkey1=myValue1\b)(?=.*\bkey2=myValue2\b)
```

The `\b` word boundary anchors make sure that only entire alphanumeric "words" are matched.

Comment: Seems to work at first sight, but I need little more tests. I will let you know :)

Comment: @Wirone: The only thing my regex requires is that `key`s begin and `value`s end with an alphanumeric character. If you can't guarantee that, there are ways around it, but they depend on the regex engine you're using, which is why I wrote my comment to your question.

Comment: Regardless of the order of the params key1 or other must start with `&params=`. Then we have pairs like `key=value` separated with `|`. At the end there may be other real-params like `&something=...` or may be end of the request string.

I will edit question once again.

Comment: @Wirone: So this regex should work. It does not care about the order of the parameters.

Comment: Yes, it works in my internal tests, also pairs like `key1=value` and `key1=value_2` are recognized correctly (as different params) which wasn't obvious for me. We've set this regex in the app and I will know tomorrow if it works in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extremely fine-tailored regex for your specific problem.  [See a live demo here.](http://rubular.com/r/3AEbqK66WA)

```
(?:^\?|&)params=(?:|[^&]*\|)([^=]+)=([^|&]*)(?=[^&]*\|\1=\2(?:[|&]|$))
|               |           |       |          |    | |    |
|               |           |       |          |    | |    Ensure the value
|               |           |       |          |    | |    is followed by a
|               |           |       |          |    | |    '|' or '&' or the
|               |           |       |          |    | |    end-of-string so
|               |           |       |          |    | |    as not to match
|               |           |       |          |    | |    a substring.
|               |           |       |          |    | |
|               |           |       |          |    | Use backreferences to
|               |           |       |          |    | refer to the preceding
|               |           |       |          |    | key/value pair found.
|               |           |       |          |    |
|               |           |       |          |    Logically it must be
|               |           |       |          |    true that the second
|               |           |       |          |    pair follows a '|'.
|               |           |       |          |
|               |           |       |          Keep searching for the
|               |           |       |          duplicate key/value pair as
|               |           |       |          long as we don't hit a '&'.
|               |           |       |
|               |           |       Consider all characters valid for a
|               |           |       value until we hit a '|' or '&'.  Also,
|               |           |       allow empty values (*).
|               |           |
|               |           Consider all characters valid for a key until we
|               |           hit a '='.  Therefore, expect having an odd
|               |           number of key/value entities to cause a problem.
|               |
|               Start searching immediately following the "params=" or after
|               a string of non-'&' characters followed by a '|'.
|
Start at the beginning of the string with a '?', or somewhere (anywhere) in
the string with a '&'.
```

Its advantages over other solutions include being more rigorous about finding complete keys (as opposed to substrings) and of course, not needing to specify specific keys at all, by using backreferences.

Notes:

1. The `\r\n`s in the demo are only for demoing purposes.
2. It is not possible to capture within lookaround assertions; hence the first set is matched without a lookaround assertion.
3. This regex does not guard against the possibility that a `value1=key1` might coincidentally match a `key1=value1`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit?

```
(key[\d]+=[^|]+)
```

Without knowing your language of choice, I can't provide a method of using it to extract groups..

This means the following:

```
Match "key" explicitly
Match any amount of numbers until you hit a non-number
Match "=" explicitly
Match any amount of characters that aren't a pipe "|"
```

This will match any amount key#=value pairs separated by pipe characters.

EDIT: In response to your comment:

```
([A-Za-z\d]+=[^|]+)
```

This means:

```
Match any amount of alphabetical characters or numbers
Match "=" explicitly
Match any character that is not a pipe character "|"
```

This will match any of the following:

```
key=value|myKey=MyValue|key2012=MyValue2012|country=usa|sex=female
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, `key1` is only as example. I need to catch two exact key=value pairs (where key and value doesn't matter for the regex, I will change it), one `key1=value1` and second `key2=value2`. It could be `sex=female` and `country=usa` for example.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, I've edited question so maybe now it's clear enough.