# How to handle possible different orders of HTML (img) element atttributes during regex extraction?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to extract values of `alt`, `src`, and values of `width` and `max-width` of `style` from an `img` element, that has a "*regexMe*" `class` and likely other classes, **regardless of order of the attributes**. I understand this is very specfic, but that is the reason why I need help, and why the many other similar Q&A such as [Regular expression for extracting tag attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes)  or [How to create a regex that will match regardless of the sequence of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138159/how-to-create-a-regex-that-will-match-regardless-of-the-sequence-of-characters) didn't do the job.

So far, I got this (https://regex101.com/r/fyqCA5/3):

```
<img(?:\s*)(?:[\D]*)regexMe(?:[\D]*)(?:\s*)src="(?'src'[^\"]*)"(?:\s*)style="(?:[^\"]*)width:(?'width'[ a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:[^\>]*)>|<img(?:\s*)(?:[\D]*)bordered"(?:[\D]*)(?:\s*)style="(?:[^\"]*)width:([ a-zA-Z0-9]*)" src="([^\"]*)"(?:[^\>]*)>
```

It works, it allows for extra spaces, extra attributes, but I don't know how to **handle the different possible orders of attributes** (e.g. `class` followed by `src` vs. `src` followed by `class`, etc..).

Helping me tackle that would be a good enough answer.

EDIT: I will be using this with javascript/Gulp.js. I don't insist on tackling this with a single do-it-all regex Other approaches are welcome :)

Comment: The best option here is to _not_ use regex to parse HTML.  Instead use an XML/HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen . Could you please be more specific on this, maybe make your reply a regular answer? I am limited by the environment (Gulp building process).

Comment: Just for the fun of it - here's a regex that uses forward lookaheads to extract each of the pieces you want: https://regex101.com/r/8C5oY1/1

Comment: @Nick YES! You also might want to post the link as possibly the shortest answer on SO, I will accept it, and head of to learn forward lookaheads :)

Comment: @marko-36 it'll probably get downvoted a lot for using regex to parse HTML. So just take it and have fun with it.

Comment: @Nick, I get you. Downvotes here are a sad thing. I could have explored the XML/HTML/XPATH parser way, but I am talking the Gulp.js build process here, so I want to make my gulpfile as simple as possible, and the need for code efficency is close to non-existent, so that nice regex of yours is optimal. Thanks again.